Why does this gyroscope derivation fail for non-punctual mass distributions?
I've been working on deriving the equations of motion for a gyroscope in spherical coordinates. The setup involves a mass distribution (e.g., a spinning disk) whose center of mass is at a fixed distance $\rho$ from the origin, such as if it were attached to a rigid bar.
The derivation and resulting equations work well when the spinning mass distribution is small compared to $\rho$ (i.e., the mass can be approximated as a point mass). However, the results no longer match numerical simulations when the mass distribution cannot be considered punctual (e.g., when the mass is spread over a larger area, like a disk with significant size relative to $\rho$).
My question is: What is the conceptual flaw in this derivation that causes it to fail for non-punctual mass distributions?
The position of the center of mass is
$$\vec{r}=\begin{bmatrix}\rho\cos(\phi)\cos(\theta)\\\rho\cos(\phi)\sin(\theta)\\\rho\sin(\phi)\end{bmatrix}$$
The angular momentum consists of orbital and spin components:
$$\vec{L} = M\left(\vec{r}\times \frac{d\vec{r}}{dt}\right) + I\vec{\omega}$$
Assuming the spin angular momentum is parallel to the gyroscope axis, we write:
$$\vec{L} = M\left(\vec{r}\times \frac{d\vec{r}}{dt}\right) + \frac{I\omega}{\rho}\vec{r}$$
Taking the time derivative:
$$\frac{d\vec{L}}{dt} = M\left(\vec{r}\times \frac{d^2\vec{r}}{dt^2}\right)+\frac{I\omega}{\rho}\vec{v}$$
This must equal the torque from external forces (gravity). From this, it can be seen that the z-component is zero. Computing $\frac{d\vec{L}}{dt}$, taking the z-component, and equaling to zero results in
$$0=M\rho^2\left(\ddot{\theta}\cos(\phi)-2\dot{\theta}\dot{\phi}\sin(\phi)\right)+I\omega\dot{\phi}$$
Solving for $\ddot{\theta}$
$$\ddot{\theta}=2\dot{\theta}\dot{\phi}\tan(\phi)-\frac{I\omega}{M\rho^2\cos(\phi)}\dot{\phi}$$
Now, the total energy is given by
$$E = Mg\rho\sin(\phi) + \frac{1}{2}Mv^2+\frac{1}{2}I\omega^2$$
Since it is conserved, the derivative is equal to zero, and the rotational term does not change because the force that keeps the mass at a fixed distance acts at the center of mass. Therefore,
$$0=g\rho\dot{\phi}\cos(\phi)+\vec{v}\cdot\frac{d\vec{v}}{dt}$$
Computing this gives
$$0=\frac{2g}{\rho}\dot{\phi}\cos(\phi)+2\dot{\phi}\ddot{\phi}+2\dot{\theta}\ddot{\theta}\cos^2(\phi)-\dot{\theta}^2\dot{\phi}\sin(2\phi)$$
Substituting the equation for $\ddot{\theta}$ and solving for $\ddot{\phi}$, we find:
$$\ddot{\phi}=\cos(\phi)\left(\frac{I\omega}{M\rho^2}\dot{\theta}-\frac{g}{\rho}\right) - \frac{\dot{\theta}^2}{2}\sin(2\phi)$$
So we have two equations for $\ddot{\theta}$ and $\ddot{\phi}$. To simulate the gyroscope, one only needs to set the initial conditions for $\theta$, $\phi$, $\dot{\theta}$ and $\dot{\phi}$.
The Issue
These two equations for $\ddot{\theta}$ and $\ddot{\phi}$ work well for simulating the gyroscope when the mass distribution is small compared to $\rho$. However, they fail when the mass distribution is significant.
What is the conceptual error in this derivation that makes it inapplicable to extended mass distributions and how would one correct for that?

where did you get those spherical coordinates? $\rho$ is usually the distance to the axis in cylindrical coordinates. The radial coordinate should be $r$. Moreover, the polar and azimuthal angle should be $\theta$ and $\phi$, respectively, with $z=r\cos\theta$. Now you have $\rho\sin\phi$, which is what one uses is $\phi$ is the latitude, in which case the azimuthal coordinate should be longitude, $\lambda$, i.e., standard geodetic coordinates. As is, it's confusing.

@JEB This is largely a matter of notation. Different textbooks and sources often use widely varying conventions, and formal courses I had at university don't align with the notation you used, for example. Ultimately, the choice of coordinates should suit the problem at hand. In this case, latitude and longitude, as you pointed out, are the most appropriate here. I do recognize it is important to ensure that the symbols used are compatible with established conventions to minimize confusion. However, as I mentioned, there isn’t a single universal standard.

Without going into the specific expressions:

Assuming the spin angular momentum is parallel to the gyroscope axis [...]

There is the following: during gyroscopic precession there is continuous internal relocation of momentum. That is, there are internal bending forces, corresponding to the internal relocation of momentum.
As a consequence: during gyroscopic precession the angular velocity vector and the angular momentum vector are close to each other, but they are not aligned.
So I'm wondering whether that could possibly be the reason your simulation shows subtle deviation from actual gyroscopic precession.

There is on youtube a demonstration of that aspect of rotational motion, in a video about another rotational effect: the Dzhanibekov effect. Name of the author of that video: David Brown, name of the youtube channel: Physics Unsimplified.
In the case of the Dzhanibekov effect (intermediate axis theorem), there is also internal relocation of momentum.

Another instance is a case usually referred to as Feynman's wobbling plate. As the plate is wobbling: the angular momentum vector has a constant direction, since the wobbling plate is not subject to any torque. The instantaneous angular velocity vector of the plate is defined as the vector perpendicular to the plane of the plate. With the plate wobbling those two vectors are not aligned. Youtube video by Jacob Forster: Feynman's wobbling plate.
Feynman's wobbling plate has the simplicity that there is no torque, so the angular momentum vector is constant. In the case of gyroscopic precession there is a torque and corresponding to that the angular momentum vector is sweeping out a cone.

This is actually extremely interesting! I didn't know about these details, and perhaps this explains why almost every study of the gyroscope I see uses this Euler's equations/angles approach, which would be very indicative of this being the reason behind the discrepancy I found. Note that this discrepancy can be extremely noticeable, and not subtle - when I use a spinning disk with 6 meters in diameter but connected to a 1 meter rod to the origin, the nutation is wildly different.
